# Android CheckBox in Listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a listview populated from the database, and a checkbox for each row. Using putExtras to pass values ​​to a TextView to another Activity. Now when you restart the app I want to display in TextView the last value selected with checkboxes. I need SharedPreferences or is there a method? Thanks

Comment: I think SharedPreferences will be the best

Comment: you can use database for it.

Comment: If number of checkboxes checked could be many then i would prefer storing in database. but, if checked item could be one or two, in that case i would prefer SharedPreference. Now, you must be knowing the nature of checkbox selection in your app, so you can relate my opinion accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Save your checkbox in preference as below:

```
//method to load the sharedpreferences. 
private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName", "YourName");
    if (checkBoxValue) {
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }

    textview.setText(name);
}
    //store boolean value of checkbox in sharedpreferences. 
private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
    //store the string sharedpreference.
private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());
    savePreferences("storedName", textview.getText().toString());

}
```